# Web Driver Element Element is not clickable c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The first click is throwing the error. This has worked many times before. Now, it's not working. I checked the class names and they are the same.

At the first wait.Until (drv) line it throws the error

> " An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll Additional information: unknown error:
>   Element is not clickable at point (-1469, 66)"

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
        // Now Click Next (Broke here first time)
        wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElements(By.ClassName("compareSelectedAddToMyBriefcaseAddToBOMLabels"))[1]).Click();
        // Click Next Again
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElements(By.ClassName("compareSelectedAddToMyBriefcaseAddToBOMLabels"))[0]).Click();
        // Click Continue
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I updated the Post.

Comment: What version of Chrome driver? And try some of these options http://learn-automation.com/how-to-solve-element-is-not-clickable-at-pointxy-in-selenium/

Comment: I expect the problem is that the item is (or extends) quite far offscreen, hence the negative x-position. I believe the driver picks a random point between the x-start and x-end and y-start and y-end, and tries to click it. If that point is offscreen, I'm not certain it will work. Can you check if the item is on the screen?

Comment: the Item is off of the screen. How can I keep everything on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone using ChromeDriver 61+ may run into this error. The recent update of the ChromeDriver V2.32 fixes this issue. I recommend updating your ChromeDriver. This should do the trick.